# Teradata SQL - Filtering different columns of the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to filter BEG_DATE and END_DATE based upon the field a.CTACT_RF. There are records in a.CTACT_RF that signal both the beginning and the end of the process. In short, I need to filter the BEG_DATE when the process starts and the END_DATE when the process has ended based upon CTACT_RF.

My current code:

```
SELECT
        k.CASE_ID,
        k.CASE_STATUS_CD,
        a.CTACT_RF,
        CAST(k.CASE_OPEN_DT AS DATE)    AS  BEG_DATE,
        CAST(MIN(a.ACTION_DTM) AS DATE) AS  END_DATE,
        CURRENT_DATE                    AS  CAL_DATE
    FROM
        k
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
        a
            ON      (a.CONTEXT_CD   =   k.CONTEXT_CD)
            AND     (a.CASE_ID      =   k.CASE_ID)
    WHERE
                    (k.CASE_STATUS_CD       =       'OPEN')         
    GROUP BY
        k.CASE_ID,
        k.CASE_STATUS_CD,
        a.CTACT_RF,
        k.CASE_OPEN_DT
```

I want to have something like:

```
SELECT
        k.CASE_ID,
        k.CASE_STATUS_CD,
        a.CTACT_RF,
        CAST((k.CASE_OPEN_DT WHERE a.CTACT_RF = 'STCOEMRESP') AS DATE)      AS  BEG_DATE,
        CAST(MIN((a.ACTION_DTM WHERE a.CTACT_RF = 'DC022') AS DATE) AS  END_DATE,
        CURRENT_DATE AS     CAL_DATE
```

for my SELECT statement, but I am getting errors.

I could use a subquery, but I'm trying to look for something cleaner as it is already a subquery.

This is in Teradata.

Comment: `CAST(CASE WHEN a.CTACT_RF = 'STCOEMRESP' THEN k.CASE_OPEN_DT END AS DATE)`

Comment: @C. Kelly:  Kindly share sample data and your desired output, then we would be able to tune in your query.